# Sum of the Bessel function of the first kind to the 4th power

Tags: mathematical-physics, bessel-functions, quantum-information

Does anyone know what the following is equal to? $$\sum^{\infty}_{n=-\infty} J_n^4(x)$$

$J_n$ is the Bessel function of the first kind of order $n$. In the quantum walk problem I'm tackling, $x$ is real and $n$ is an integer such that $J_n (x)$ is always real.

Am familiar with following identities $J_{-n} (x) = (-1)^n J_n(x)$ and $ \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty J_n^2(x) = 1$ from grad school but not sure how to make use of these (or if they're at all useful!)

Comment: look at equation (20) in [this article](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1751-8113/41/1/015207)

Comment: @AbolfazlChamanmotlagh Paywalled. Can you give a summary result?

Comment: it has 2 steps, first observe that if $t_n(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} h(\theta,x) e^{in\theta} d\theta$ then we have $\sum_n | t_n(x) |^2 = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} |h(\theta,x)|^2 d\theta$ . (Parseval's theorem). then from Neumann's formula we have : $J_n^2(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} J_0\big(2x \sin[\theta/2]\big) e^{in\theta} d\theta$. so if we choose $t_n(x)=J_n^2(x)$ we get :
$$
\sum_n J_n^4(x) = \frac{2}{\pi} \int_0^{\pi/2} J_0^2(2x \sin\theta)d\theta
$$

Comment: Thanks @AbolfazlChamanmotlagh, that solves it!